# Limit of the sum and Cauchy theorem on limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If a sequence
$\{x_n\}$
 converges to l, then the sequence
$\{y_n\}$
 also converges to l,
where $y_n=x_1+x_2+\cdots +\dfrac{x_n}{n}$.

I suspect that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{2k-1}{n^2}$ is 2, using Cauchy theorem, but the answer is 1. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

[My computation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsd4z.jpg)

Comment: Note that $\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)=n^2$. Do you mean $y_n=\frac{x_1+x_2+⋯+x_n}{n}$?

Comment: Yes I meant Cauchy theorem for limits

Comment: Why my computation is wrong?

Comment: @Josh Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{n^2}=\frac2{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k-\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n 1=\frac2{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac1n$$

The first claim is true for

$$y_n=\frac{x_1+x_2+⋯+x_n}{n}\to l$$

by Stolz-Cesaro.